# How to manage stock before to the shipping?

Tags: order

I have a problem with the handling of an order once it has been confirmed and has already been shipped to customers.

Suppose our initial order is as follows, and we don't know which customers will shipping products

[image: no customer's initial order]

Once the order is confirmed the order is sent to different customers:

[image: Order sent to various customers]

### Now

Suppose that once the products have been shipped, the company that manages the order, receives news that has no availability of certain sizes for products and then is forced to change some amount from the initial order, where it owns the inventories for the various products / sizes

So make the change to the product sizes

[image: modified sizes]

How do I manage and then update the "table" with inside the quantities shipped to customers with the new amount? How can I fix the goods? I have to clear the shipment and to redo the assignment with the customer or are there other ways?

Comment: Hm, are not customers typically the ones who create orders for products, so the order gets shipped to a supplier, which ships a product back to the customer? Did I get you wrong, or is the flow in your case in the opposite direction?

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, this is just one example that I want to find a solution.

Comment: Expecially when it is just an example I have problems to understand why you used the terms this way.

Comment: The problem is not "how to change orders already shipped". It's rather, "how to manage stock before to the shipping". If you have no access to the stock. Would not be two different orders? could you cancel the first one and create a new one?. I would not delete, clear, modify the canceled in order to track the whole lifecycle of the order (linking orders).

Comment: @Laiv Yes, the title you described is much better for this problem. Yes, if the order was only one, and with all amount to an individual client I could delete and redo.

Comment: Would be useful to know your domain data model and the implementation details. Otherwise, no solution here is going to suite your expectations

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to handle this (telegram format).

First is a cancellation of the order. This will revert the order, send a refund, etc.

The second way is to create a substitution order which links to the real order. It will track late delivery and handles negotiation with the customer about delays.

The long answer will take an expensive consulting job, I guess xD

Comment: The second solution would work, but in the case of `Prod3`, which has been shipped to several customers to which of them I send what I have in stock? Random?

Comment: Without requirements it's hard to tell. I'd use some rating of customers. The devil takes the hindmost.